# How to show $0 < \frac{x}{x+y} < 1$ given $0 < x$ and $0 < y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to help my student understand why it is true that

$$0 < \frac{x}{x+y} < 1 \impliedby 0 < x \text{ , } 0 < y$$

I so far say that intuitively, $\frac{x}{x}=1$ and since $0<y$ we know 
$$\frac{x}{x+y} \lt 1$$

when $y$ is close to $0$.

But when $y$ is much bigger

$$0<\frac{x}{x+y}$$.

She really has trouble with "intuition" but she does very well with rigorous algebraic proofs.

Is there an "algebraic" approach to this situation?

A would appreciate your help.

Comment: You can multiply the whole inequality by $x+y$(it's not zero and it's positive) then you get $0<x<x+y$ which is the same as $0<x$ and $x<x+y$ and this is same as $0<y$

Comment: If $y > 0$ then $x + y > x$.  So $1 = \frac {x+y}{x+y} > \frac {x}{x+y}$.  Likewise $0 < \frac {x}{x+y} < 1$ if and only if $\frac{x+y}{x} > 1$.  And $\frac {x+y}x = \frac xx + \frac yx = 1 + \frac yx > 1$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since $x$ and $y$ are greater than zero, we can divide by $x + y$ without messing up inequalities.

So if $0 < x < x + y$, which is clear, then $\frac{0}{x + y} < \frac{x}{x+y} < \frac{x+y}{x + y}$, which just states $0 < \frac{x}{x+y} < 1$

Comment: Oh, my, THIS is exactly the type of answer that I was looking for!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: @hyg17 You're welcome. I hope it helps your student.

Comment: It has.  The biggest challenge is that she is 7 and her language skills are not developed but she understands math at pre-calc level.  Her mind works differently and she unexpectedly gets stuck at concepts that I would assume that she understands but her verbal skills and math skills are for some reason independent from each other.

Comment: @hyg17 seven years old, that seems like quite the challenge. I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

If:
$$x,y>0$$
then:
$$x+y>x$$
$$x+y>y$$
and so:
$$\frac x{x+y}<1$$
$$\frac y{x+y}<1$$
also since all terms are greater than $0$, you have a positive number divided by a positive number, which must be positive, and so:
$$\frac x{x+y}>0$$
$$\frac y{x+y}>0$$

Answer (score 1):

Similar to one of the answers, but succinctly: since $x, y > 0,$

$$0 = \frac{0}{x + y} < \frac{x}{x + y} < \frac{x}{x} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

We can explain by the following simple rules:

- **Rule 1.** Sum of two positive numbers is a positive number.
- **Rule 2.** Quotient of two positive numbers is a positive number.
- **Rule 3.** Subtracting a positive number we get a smaller result.

Since $x>0,y>0$, $x+y>0$ by Rule 1, and $\displaystyle\frac{x}{x+y}>0$ and 
$\displaystyle\frac{y}{x+y}>0$ by Rule 2. Finally, by Rule 3, we have

$$
\frac{x}{x+y}=\frac{(x+y)-y}{x+y}=1-\frac{y}{x+y}<1.
$$